# Segmentation fault with recieved signal SIGSEGV

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, gdb, tail

I'm working on an implementation of the `tail` Unix command, and this is my code so far:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *resize(char *data, int size)
{
    char *newData = (char*) malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int counter;

    for(counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
        newData[counter] = data[counter];
    free(data);
    return newData;
}

int printLines(char *data, int size)
{
    int lines = 0, position, counter;

    for(position = size - 1; position > -1; position--)
    {
        if (data[position] == '\n') lines++;
        if (lines == 10) break;
    }

    if (lines == 10)
        for(counter = position; counter < size; counter++)
        {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &data[counter], 1);
        }
    else write(STDOUT_FILENO, data, size);
    return 0;
}

int stdIn(char *data, int size)
{
    char buff, end = '\n';
    int rState = 0;

    while ((rState = read(STDIN_FILENO, &buff, 1)) > 0)
    {
        if(rState < 0)
        {
            if(errno == EINTR) rState = 0;
            else
            {
                perror("read()");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        data = resize(data, size);
        data[size - 1] = buff;
        size++;
    }

    if(rState == 0) write(STDOUT_FILENO, &end, 1);
    return 0;
}

int tailRead(char *data, char *fileName)
{
    int size = 1;
    data = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    if(fileName == 0 || fileName == "-")
    {
        if(stdIn(data, size) > 0) return 1;
    }
    else
    {

    }

    printLines(data, size);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *data = 0;
    int counter;

    if(argc == 1)
    {
        tailRead(data, 0);
        if(data > 0) return 1;
    }
    else for (counter = 1; counter < argc; counter++)
    {
        tailRead(data, argv[counter]);
        if(data > 0) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that somewhere in the `resize()` function i get a Segmentation Fault, and when i ran the program in GDB, i got `Program received signal SIGSEGV  Segmentation fault. 0x00000000004006f7 in resize ()`. This tells me that I have some kind of memory allocation problem in `resize()`, but so far I have been unable to find the bug. What should I do?

Comment: `resize(data, size);` --> `data=resize(data, size);`

Comment: OT: Also you might like to have a look at the `realloc()` function.

Comment: that was a copy-paste mistake, the error is still there

Comment: If you're on *nix, you may want to `valgrind` this puppy (make sure you compile with `-g` first.) That'll give you the exact line of code that the error is on, and usually a full stack trace.

Comment: Your `printLines` function is being called with a freed `data` pointer.

Comment: Yes, i noticed it just now, for some reason after i just compiled it, the Segmentation fault just disappeared. The `printLines()` i can fix.

Comment: @Reaper9806 the place, where the signal arrived in your code is not precise. Use `gdb` to step through your code. Maybe you'll prefer a graphical front end like e.g. `ddd`. I am pretty sure, you'll find the error to be a dangling `data`-pointer in `tailRead()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int tailRead(char *data, char *fileName)
/* ... */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *data = 0;
    /* ... */
        tailRead(data, 0);
}
```

You seem to expect, that in `main()` `data` will point to the memory allocated in `tailRead()`. That is not the case. In `tailRead()` `data` is a copy of the pointer `data` from `main()` you only change the copy, not the original pointer. The original pointer still points to `0`.

Then you call `resize()` with a null pointer, which of course will lead to a segmentation violation.

**Solution**

use a pointer to a pointer instead, to modify the original pointer.

```
int tailRead(char **data, char *fileName)
{
    int size = 1;
    *data = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));

    /* ... */
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *data = 0;
     /* ... */
        tailRead(&data, 0);
     /* ... */
}
```

You have the same issue with `stdIn()`. It changes `data` without reflecting the change to the `data`-pointer at the call site in `tailRead()`. You leave `stdIn()` leaking memory and continue to work with a dangling pointer.

Comment: actually, the `chat *` in `main()` isn't going to serve any purpose, I was only using it as a sort of starting point in the beginning, I'm going to modify the `tailRead()` function to not require thr `char *data` argument, as it is only used within the functions above, and after `printLines()` it serves on other purpose.

Comment: @Reaper9806 You have the same issue with `stdIn()`. You change the pointer inside with `data = resize(data, size)`. That will not be reflected at the call side in `tailRead()`. `printLines` will be called with a pointer to freed memory. BTW.: Is there a good reason not to use `realloc()` instead of `resize()`? In case the memory layout allows it, `realloc()` will avoid copying and just change the size of the allocated memory chunk.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is here...

```
    for(counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
        newData[counter] = data[counter];
```

You are trying to access `data[counter]` when counter is greater than what you allocated for the previous `malloc()`.  By this I mean, you are reading beyond the (current) legitimate end of `data`.  Make sense?

EDIT: Now that I think about it, this may not cause the segfault, but it is a problem.

Comment: I've tested it several times, this was never an issue.

Comment: I agree, it probably didn't cause your segfault, but you are addressing and copying an uninitialized byte of data.  You should be using `for(counter = 0; counter < size-1; counter++)`